# cron php how to stop headers in append to file

Tags: php, header, cron

cron command:

```
     /user/bin/php "/path/Script.php" >> /path/LogFile.html
```

when php outputs to my log file, it always starts off by saying

```
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.22 Content-type: text/html
```

so with my output file, it looks something like:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.22 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.22 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.22 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.22 Content-type: text/html
 NEW DAY MARKER | 29/04/2013 00:00:07
 Total Exchanges: 73294
 Total GMT references: 7
 Exchanges pending approval: 4
```

the output is in a table format, causing the the repeated text/html header to flood the first 4 or 5 pages of my log file - because they are between

```
   </tr> X-Powered-By: text/html <tr>
```

tags.

is there anyway i can tell it not to put out that kind of header information when running cron jobs? (i don't want to disable it globaly - need web interface to still work with other PHP scripts)

linux host, cpanel, vps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/user/bin/php -q "/path/Script.php" >> /path/LogFile.html
```

the `-q` switch will run it in quiet mode which will disable header output

[php command line help](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) for more switches

Comment: For me, "php -v" returns "ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc.
PHP 7.0.32 (cli) (built: Nov  7 2018 04:55:01) ( NTS )". Even though it's the CLI, the "-q" switch does not suppress the "X-Powered-By" and "Content-type" headers. ("php -h" does not list "-q" as an option.) Only adding: "header_remove("X-Powered-By"); header_remove("Content-type");" worked for me.